# Get progress notifications with MultipartFormDataStreamProvider and web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am currently using this code to submit some files to my web api controller with ajax.

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/04/html5-drag-and-drop-asynchronous-multi-file-upload-with-asp-net-webapi/

I am wondering if there is any way that i can use the [MultipartFormDataStreamProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatastreamprovider%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to get progress notifications on the files being received/written to disk.

I know there is HTML5 api for this, but i can not use this because i need progress notifications in IE 9.

It is my intend to send these changes to the client with SignalR.
This needs to happen using drag and drop so i can't use a plugin like uploadify.

Answer (score 0):

> I know there is HTML5 api for this, but i can not use this because i
>   need progress notifications in legacy browsers.

You could use a file upload plugin such as [`Uploadify`](http://www.uploadify.com/) which will test the capabilities of the browser and fallback if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion Darin, I have updated my question to state my use case more clearly. I feel like getting server side notifications should be trivial, i appreciate your help.

Comment: Using server side notifications in a stateless protocol such as HTTP is much harder. You mentioned SignalR which uses WebSockets and in the same time you are mentioning that you are using some legacy browsers that do not support the HTML 5 File API so it is even less probable that they support WebSockets. As far as using Uploadify with Drag & Drop there's absolutely nothing preventing you from using it. By the way drag and drop of what? A file from the desktop into the browser? Does your browser support that? Really SignalR is the least appropriate technology to use for this.

Comment: Yes my browser supports that, the targeted browser is IE 9. IE 9 allows drag and drop and ajax file uploads but not the new HTML 5 progress support. So SignalR will work fine for my notifications. I just need some way to get the progress on the server side. SignalR can use WebSockets, it can also fall back to long polling and works even in IE 8.

Comment: long polling is just wrong to be used in this case. Uploadify could use Flash to upload the file and which supports progress notifications which will be millions of times more performant than polling.

Comment: I certainly agree, however, i will not be able to use this because i really need drag and drop support, which is impossible to use with uploadify.

Comment: No, that's not true. Drag & Drop (as you already mentioned) is supported by IE9. You will implement it with the native javascript methods. Only the actual file upload will be performed with `Uploadify`.

Comment: You are correct once again, it is supported by IE9. But not by uploadify. Our am i mistaken ?

Comment: But you won't use Uploadify for drag and drop. Only for file upload once the file has been dropped into a file input field in the form.

Comment: I don't think you can use an input field form with uploadify, it uses strictly a flash button for input. could you please provide a short code example if i am mistaken ?

Comment: I am not sure about `Uploadify` (as I haven't used it, but I am almost certain it can be done, just don't have the time to read the documentation now) but you could do that with the BlueImp file upload plugin: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

Comment: blueimp is very nice but does not provide any progress support in IE9. If you could just provide me with some directions on how to get the progress on the server side then that would really help me out i think. Thank you for your time so far.

Comment: That's not something I would be looking to implement on the server. It's just the wrong side.

Comment: I absolutely agree, however, do you have any suggestion on how to get progress notifications with drag and drop to work in IE9 with ASP.NET? that is really my only requirement.

Comment: Yes, I would look into the documentation of the available file upload plugins.

Comment: By the way, from what I can see (http://caniuse.com/#feat=dragndrop) IE9 has a very limited support of Drag & Drop - only 16% of the specification. Are you even sure that it works with files?

Comment: 100%, i have already tested this, but it does not support the progress events i need. That's why i need a work around, sadly enough uploadify /blueimp is not the answer, i assure you that i have read the documentation extensively. If you have any other ideas i would love to hear them.

Comment: also doing this from the server doesn't sound **that** crazy to me, this has been done for years before the HTML 5 features came available. Sure it's not the most efficient way, but right now it does seem like the only way for legacy browers, it's pretty sad i have to count IE9 with that.

Comment: Maybe you are right then. Sorry, I can't help with this. Personally I have stopped worrying about such legacy browsers long time ago. People that are using them will just have to embrace the reality and live with it (in this case without upload progress). I really wouldn't invest so much time and jeopardize the stability of the application (by implementing some horrible server side hacks) for something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your understanding. However i can not give up on legacy browsers... The answer also doesn't seem that far away. If i could just get some sort of feedback from MultipartFormDataStreamProvider then i could push those changes with signalr and progress events would work in IE9, that's really the only priority i have here, making sure it works.

Comment: Good luck in that direction.